# Should we consolidate questions on the Evil Dead franchise under a single tag (with or without sub-tags)?

Tags: discussion, tags

[army-of-darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/army-of-darkness) has several questions.

A [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54627/1359) was recently asked that was (appropriately) tagged [evil-dead-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil-dead-2).

One of the *Army of Darkness* questions [also relates to *Evil Dead 2*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9629/1359).

Should these tags be consolidated into one [franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead_(franchise)) tag (e.g. [evil-dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil-dead))?  Should they remain distinct, with [evil-dead-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil-dead-2) being added to my earlier *Army of Darkness* tag?  Is there another solution that would be preferable?

Note that there are currently 4 movies in the franchise (the original *Evil Dead* from 1981, the sequal *Evil Dead 2: Dead By Dawn* from 1987,  *Army of Darkness* from 1992, and the remake *Evil Dead* from 2013).  Additionally, there are [rumors of a upcoming sequel to *Army of Darkness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead_(franchise)#Evil_Dead_2.2C_Army_of_Darkness_2.2C_and_crossover_film), as well as [video games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead_(franchise)#Video_games), [comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead_(franchise)#Comic_books) and a [musical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead_(franchise)#Musical).